# How can I create a "Launcher" Activity programmatically?

Tags: android

Instead of declaring a pre-determined launcher activity in my manifest using an intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Could I, instead, be given programmatic control over the activity which gets run when the application launches?

I'm not able to find anywhere in the documentation which says I *must* use the intent filter approach... but I also don't see any discussion of the alternative(s).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible. Android creates or sets up the hard link of the App icons to their respective activities by looking at the manifest. If you don't set it, you will not find any icons/shortcuts for your app after you install it.

Comment: In that case, do you know if it's possible to change this value post-deployment?

Comment: Nope. You can't change the manifest after installing the app. However, a possible workaround that might help you would be to maintain a flag somewhere after the first launch, and then check for this flag everytime in your Default activity, finish your default activity and start the required one.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like creating a super light-weight activity is really the only way. Blah. Thanks for your help.